# joining two tables with one table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table `pa_master_details` and `lov_details`.

In the `pa_master_details` table, I have `role_comp_emp_final_rating` and `role_comp_lm_final_rating` columns.

In the `lov_details` table I have a column rating `lov_value` and `lov_text_en`.

I need to join `role_comp_emp_final_rating` with the `lov_value` column to get `lov_text_en`
Based on this `lov_value`, I need to show `lov_text_en` from the `lov_details` table.

So I wrote a query like this and am getting the result for emp rating:

```
SELECT p.employee_number,
       p.role_comp_emp_final_rating,
       lov_text_en,
       p.role_comp_lm_final_rating
FROM pa_master_details P, lov_details L
WHERE p.role_comp_emp_final_rating = l.lov_value
AND p.employee_number = 34570
```

Similarly, I need to show `lov_text_en` for `role_comp_lm_final_rating` from the `lov_details` table by joining 
`role_comp_lm_final_rating` with `lov_value` in the same query.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
SELECT p.employee_number,
       p.role_comp_emp_final_rating,
       lemp.lov_text_en AS "emp_lov_text",
       llm.lov_text_en AS "lm_lov_text",
       p.role_comp_lm_final_rating
FROM pa_master_details p
JOIN (SELECT lov_text FROM lov_details) lemp ON p.role_comp_emp_final_rating = lemp.lov_value
JOIN (SELECT lov_text FROM lov_details) llm  ON p.role_comp_lm_final_rating  = llm.lov_value
WHERE p.employee_number = 34570
```

Comment: Hi Rob,  Thanks for reply .I tried but not getting the result.   SELECT p.employee_number,
       p.role_comp_emp_final_rating,
       lemp.lov_text_en ,
       llm.lov_text_en ,
       p.role_comp_lm_final_rating
FROM PA_MASTER_DETAILS P
JOIN (SELECT * FROM LOV_DETAILS) LEMP ON P.ROLE_COMP_EMP_FINAL_RATING = LEMP.LOV_VALUE
JOIN (SELECT * FROM LOV_DETAILS ) LLM  ON P.ROLE_COMP_LM_FINAL_RATING  = LLM.LOV_VALUE
WHERE P.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '61010'

Comment: I noticed I made an error with the aliases because I forgot to update them in the `ON` clauses. I see you fixed them in your comment, right? What is the error you are getting?